# Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using multiplot in gnuplot to insert four graphs in the single figure. My code looks like this:

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set xlabel 'i'
set ylabel 'j'
set xtics 20
set ytics 20
set xlabel font ",20"
set ylabel font ",20"
set pm3d map
set pm3d corners2color c1
set out "Rulkovpattern.eps"
set multiplot layout 2,2
set title "(a)"
set size square 0.55,0.55
spl 'patternD0pt02.dat' notitle
set title "(b)"
set size square 0.55,0.55
spl 'patternD0pt04.dat' notitle
set size square 0.55,0.55
set title "(c)"
spl 'patternD0pt06.dat' notitle
set size square 0.55,0.55
set title "(d)"
spl 'patternD0pt08.dat' notitle
unset multiplot
set out
set term wxt
```

This generates the following picture:
[image: patterns]

But in this picture, there is a lot of blank space in the middle. I would like to make that space disappear or at least make it as minimum as possible. How can I do it by modifying my code?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Getting the margins right with `multiplot` is a bit tedious, especially when using `set pm3d map`, which has quite large margins.

## Since version 5.0

Since 5.0 version,`multiplot` has the options `margins` and `spacing`.

`margins` takes four numbers `set multiplot margins <left>,<right>,<bottom>,<top>`, which give the fixed overall margins around the multiplot layout. `spacing` takes two number `set multiplot spacing <xspacing>,<yspacing>` which give the distance between two rows (`<yspacing>`) or two columns (`<xspacing>`).

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 background rgb '#bbbbbb'
set output 'foobar.png'

set multiplot layout 2,2 \
              margins 0.1,0.98,0.1,0.98 \
              spacing 0.08,0.08

set ylabel 'ylabel'
plot x

unset ylabel
plot 2*x

set ylabel 'ylabel'
set xlabel 'xlabel'
plot 3*x

unset ylabel
plot 4*x
unset multiplot
```

Result (with 5.0rc1):

[image]

## Earlier versions, kept only for completeness

To achieve the same thing with gnuplot 4.x, you must do the calculations by hand or define some functions, like the following example shows. This should be quite universally usable.

You can put all the general stuff in a configuration file, like `multiplot.gp`, which contains the functions

```
init_margins(left, right, bottom, top, dx, dy, rows, cols) = \
  sprintf('left_margin = %f; right_margin = %f; top_margin = %f; bottom_margin = %f; ', left, right, top, bottom) . \
  sprintf('col_count = %d; row_count = %d; gap_size_x = %f; gap_size_y = %f', cols, rows, dx, dy)

get_lmargin(col) = (left_margin + (col - 1) * (gap_size_x + ((right_margin - left_margin)-(col_count - 1) * gap_size_x)/col_count))
get_rmargin(col) = (left_margin + (col - 1) * gap_size_x + col * ((right_margin - left_margin)-(col_count - 1) * gap_size_x)/col_count)
get_tmargin(row) = (top_margin  - (row - 1) * gap_size_y - (row-1) * ((top_margin - bottom_margin  - gap_size_y * row_count) / row_count))
get_bmargin(row) = (top_margin  - (row - 1) * gap_size_y -  row    * ((top_margin - bottom_margin  - gap_size_y * row_count) / row_count))
set_margins(col, row) = \
  sprintf('set lmargin at screen %f;', get_lmargin(col)) . \
  sprintf('set rmargin at screen %f;', get_rmargin(col)) . \
  sprintf('set tmargin at screen %f;', get_tmargin(row)) . \
  sprintf('set bmargin at screen %f;', get_bmargin(row))
```

The main file is then

```
set terminal pngcairo size 800,600 background rgb '#bbbbbb'
set output 'foobar2.png'

load 'multiplot.gp'

eval(init_margins(0.1, 0.98, 0.1, 0.98, 0.08, 0.08, 2, 2))    
set multiplot

eval(set_margins(1,1))
set ylabel 'ylabel'
plot x

eval(set_margins(2,1))
unset ylabel
plot 2*x

eval(set_margins(1,2))
set ylabel 'ylabel'
set xlabel 'xlabel'
plot 3*x

eval(set_margins(2,2))
unset ylabel
plot 4*x
unset multiplot
```

With the result (using 4.6.4):

[image]

Comment: I like it how your answers always beat mine with features of still to be released versions of gnuplot: +1

Comment: @Bernhard :) Sorry for this, it was a bit unfair: I implemented this feature for gnuplot, so I was the first to know about it. The other 'alternative' part was taken from my scripts of my thesis.

Comment: I never knew why this feature was not yet included, so no reason to apologize :)

Comment: Thank you very much Christoph. I really appreciate your elaborate answer and the code you wrote. But now how do I adjust the size of whole canvas so that whole canvas would be filled by plot and there would be no blank margins?

Comment: You adjust the size of the canvas with e.g. `set terminal postscript eps size 5in,4in`. The coordinates used in `init_margins` are from `0` to `1` relative to the whole canvas size. So, if the outer margins are still too large, you must adapt the according values for `<left>` etc.

Answer (score 2):

In `multiplot` by using `set lmargin`, `set rmargin`, `set bmargin` and `set tmargin`, for left, right, bottom, top margin around your graph, you have the best control of the positioning of your graphs. In my experience it gives you a bit more freedom than the `layout` option you are using now.

A good example of how to does this for a single graph is found here: http://www.gnuplotting.org/multiplot-placing-graphs-next-to-each-other/

Another approach is to define functions to set the margin, which is easier if all your graphs are the same size, see: http://www.sciencetronics.com/greenphotons/?p=570

Comment: Thanks.. But now adjusting all the margins as required, leaves space on two sides of the plot. I can of course crop the image and get rid of it but that will diminish the quality of picture I guess. Is there any other way to solve this problem?

Comment: @SnehalShekatkar I think in the second link you find an example that does that. It depends on the terminal what the easiest strategy is, for the png terminal for example, you have the crop option.

Answer (score 0):

If all have the same xlabel and ylabel you can use this

```
set terminal postscript eps enhanced color
set output 'YOUR_GRAPH.eps'

L = 0.14
R = 0.95

TOP=0.98
DY = 0.29

set multiplot

set offset 0,0,graph 0.05, graph 0.05

set ylabel 'XLABEL' offset 1
set xlabel 'YLABEL'


set tmargin at screen TOP-1.65*DY
set bmargin at screen TOP-3*DY
set lmargin at screen R-6*L
set rmargin at screen R-3*L
plot "YOUR_DATA.dat" title"TITLE 1" 

set ytics format ''
unset ylabel
set lmargin at screen R-3*L
set rmargin at screen R
plot "YOUR_DATA2.dat" title"TITLE 2"


####################################################################

set format y "%.2f"
set ylabel 'd' offset 1
set tmargin at screen TOP
set bmargin at screen TOP-1.35*DY

set lmargin at screen R-6*L
set rmargin at screen R-3*L
plot "YOUR_DATA3.dat" title"TITLE 3"

set ytics format ''
unset ylabel
set lmargin at screen R-3*L
set rmargin at screen R
plot "YOUR_DATA4.dat" title"TITLE 4"
```