# Setting common colorbox for all graphs in multiplot in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am generating a multiplot with 2 rows and 2 columns. I am using pm3d map for individual graphs. The generated picture is shown below:

[image]

In this picture, each individual graph has its own colorbox and axes labels. I would like to have common colorbox for all these graphs and would like to give common i and j indices after drawing common x and y axes. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its basically the same as I did with the xlabel and ylabel in my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213. Only that you also need to set/unset the colorbox and maybe also set empty formats for the x and y axis.

Comment: But how do I change the size of the colorbox then? I would like to have colorbox of the size of whole graph.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Christoph mentioned, this can be done with `set`/`unset` `colorbox`. In your case, I highly recommend that you `plot ... with image` rather than use `set pm3d map`. But it can be done both ways, see Christoph's comment below.

What you need is something along these lines (change the details to accommodate it to your needs):

```
set multiplot
# Set left and right margins for both plots:
set lmargin screen 0.1 ; set rmargin screen 0.8
# Set ranges and *in this case* isosamples to make the graph look better
set xrange [-1:1] ; set yrange [-1:1] ; set isosamples 100
# Options for the first graph: set top and bottom margins and unset colorbox
set tmargin screen 0.9 ; set bmargin screen 0.6 ; unset colorbox
# Plot it
plot "++" u ($1):($2):(sin($1*$2)) with image
# Options for second graph
set tmargin screen 0.4 ; set bmargin screen 0.1
# Set colorbox with customize options
set colorbox user origin 0.85,0.1 size 0.05,0.8
# Plot it
plot "++" u ($1):($2):(cos($1*$2)) with image
```

Voilà:

[image]

Comment: The image is equivalent if you use `set pm3d map; splot ... with pm3d`. In both cases (`image` and `pm3d`) you can adjust the margins like you want. I also prefer `image` over `pm3d map`, but it doesn't always work. `image` requires a regular grid (equally spaced x-values and y-values) and doesn't support contours, interpolation etc.

Comment: @Christoph At least on gnuplot 4.4 setting the margins doesn't work with `set pm3d map`, or is there a special way to do it?

Comment: Just add a `set pm3d map` to the script in your answer, change the `plot ... with image` to `splot ... with pm3d` and run it. I get the same results with 4.4.4, 4.6.4 and 5.0rc1.

Comment: @Christoph Yes, you're absolutely right, I got confused somehow. I remember having trouble with this in the past. It might have been a even older version or maybe I'm just getting old :-S