# Adjusting position of individual plots in gnuplot multiplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am using multiplot to plot four graphs. My code is given below

```
set term postscript eps enhanced color
set pm3d map
set pm3d corners2color c1
set size square
set out 'defect2.eps'
unset colorbox
set colorbox horiz user origin 0.1,0.7 size 0.8,0.02
set cbrange [-1.6:0]
set xtics 25
set ytics 25
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.9
set multiplot layout 1,4
set xlabel "i" font "Times-italic,20"
set ylabel "j" font "Times-italic,20"
spl 'defect.dat' notitle
unset ylabel
spl 'defect_2.dat' notitle
spl 'defect_3.dat' notitle
spl 'defect_4.dat' notitle
unset multiplot
set out
```

This produces a following plot

[image: defect]

However, individual plots in the picture are not properly placed. I cannot see ylabel for the first plot as it is hidden behind the screen whereas there are large blank gaps between those plots. Is there any way to reduce these gaps, increase size of these plots and show the labels properly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The code you posted doesn't produce the image you show. And you already asked an almost identical question some time ago: [Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23927580/2604213).

Comment: I am not sure what is the issue with code. It does produce the image I posted (it takes data from some data files). True that I asked a similar question some time back but there you gave me a code to adjust margins in a particular setup (2,2 layout). I would really want to be general about this. For example, removing gaps, adjsuting margins, changing sizes of only some of the plots in multiplot and so on. Kindly let me know if I am missing something obvious. Thank you

Comment: You can use the `offset` option in both `set ytics` and `set ylabel` with some positive x value to bring text and tick numbers closer to the graph. E.g. `set ytics offset 5,0` and `set ylabel "Some label" offset 8,0`. Play with the specific numbers to get the effect you desire.

Comment: Right, that question is about a 2x2 setup, but the code in my answer is so general, that you can also apply it to your case, since you can specify the number of columns and the number of rows for the layout. Since you don't provide any data files to allow to reproduce your image, I replaced any data file with a function and you get a single plot area, because you once specify an absolute left and an absolute right margin *for all* following splots (so that the `layout` option doesn' have any effect).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem is your margin  setting. The margin defines the size of the white stripe between the box containing the plot and the border of the window.

This means, tic and axis labels are printet *on* the Martin area! And your 10% of window width is not enough, so the labels are clipped.

So you can adjust the margins to shift all plots more  to the left or adjust label font sites and offsets (Miguel's comment).