# Curves superimposed to a surface in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I am trying to create a plot with gnuplot  where some curves are superimposed to a surface.
This is the code I use

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
xwidth=16.2
set size 1,1

set terminal epslatex color size xwidth cm,0.59*xwidth font 9 header '\fontsize{10}{13.2} \usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}\usepackage{amsmath} \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}' dashlength 2.0 round standalone
set output "Pernal12.tex"
set border 0 lw 0
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set multiplot

####
set size 0.55,1.166
set origin 0.02,-0.035

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [0:10]

unset ylabel
unset xlabel 

set format y ''
set format x ''
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset label 


set view map
set isosamples  400, 400
set style data pm3d
set style function pm3d
set pm3d implicit at b
#set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
#set palette positive nops_allcF maxcolors 0 gamma 1.5 gray
set palette defined (0 "white", 10 "black")

set pm3d interpolate 1,1
spacing 1.1
set cbrange[0:10]
unset colorbox
t={1,0}
e0={1,0}
eta={0.1,0}
i={0.0,1.0}
c(x)=sqrt(16*t**2+x**2)
a(x)=sqrt(2*((4*t/(c(x)-x))**2+1))
A(x)=(1-4*t/(c(x)-x))**2
B(x)=(1+4*t/(c(x)-x))**2
Gbup(x,y)=1/a(x)**2*(A(x)/(y-(e0+t+(c(x)+x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta)+B(x)/(y-(e0+t-(c(x)-x)/2)+x /2+1+i*eta))
Gaup(x,y)=1/a(x)**2*(B(x)/(y-(e0-t+(c(x)+x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta)+A(x)/(y-(e0-t-(c(x)-x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta))
splot -imag(Gbup(x,y)+Gaup(x,y))/1.01 notitle




####
unset border
set border 15 lw 1
set size 0.385,0.83

set origin 0.087,0.11
unset xtics
unset ytics

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [0:20]
set xlabel '$U/t$'
set ylabel '$\omega/t$' offset 1.0,0
set xtics 5.0
set mxtics 5
set label '$n = 1/2$' left at graph 0,1 offset 2.2,-1.6 front
set xtics ("0" 0,"" 1 1,"" 2 1,"" 3 1,"" 4 1, '5' 5,"" 6 1,"" 7 1,"" 8 1,"" 9 1, '10' 10)
set ytics ( '-6' 6,"" 5 1,"-4" 4,"" 3 1,"-2" 2,"" 1 1, "0" 0,"" -1 1,"2" -2,"" -3 1,"4" -4, "" -5 1, "6" -6)


set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
plot    'Pernal12sym.dat'  u ($1):(-$8) w l lw 2.5 lc rgb "green"     lt 2 notitle

q
```

I obtain a nice figure but the problem is its dimension, more than 10 Mb.
I could reduce the isosamples value but then the surface map resolution would be too low.
Is there a way to obtain a quite high resolution with a final .ps file whith a dimension under let's say 1Mb?

I also tried to save before the surface map in png and than using this script

```
#!/usr/bin/gnuplot
xwidth=16.2
set size 1,1

set terminal epslatex color size xwidth cm,0.59*xwidth font 9 header '\fontsize{10}{13.2} \usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}\usepackage{amsmath} \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{ptm}\usepackage{graphicx}' dashlength 2.0 round standalone
set output "Pernal12.tex"
set border 0 lw 0
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set multiplot

####
set size 0.55,1.166
set origin 0.02,-0.035

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [0:10]

unset ylabel
unset xlabel 

set format y ''
set format x ''
unset xtics
unset ytics
unset label 

plot "Pernal13.png" binary filetype=png w rgbimage 

unset border
set border 15 lw 1
set size 0.385,0.83

set origin 0.087,0.11
unset xtics
unset ytics

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [0:20]
set xlabel '$U/t$'
set ylabel '$\omega/t$' offset 1.0,0
set xtics 5.0
set mxtics 5

set grid noxtics noytics noztics front
plot    'Pernal12sym.dat'  u ($1):(-$8) w l lw 2.5 lc rgb "green"     lt 2 notitle
q
```

But at the end I don't have my .png image as the background of the .ps file.

Comment: See e.g. my answer on TeX.SX, [Big data surface plots: Call gnuplot from tikz to generate bitmap and include automatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23927580/2604213) for an example about how to achieve this. If you have the opportunity to use 5.0rc2 (or try it out), you can use the `level3` option to save the data of `plot ... with image` as png inside the postscript image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that kind of plots (equidistant sampling in x- and y-directions) it is worth using the `image` plotting style. Since I don't have the data file to test the whole script, here is the first part using `plot '++' ... with image` instead of `splot ... with pm3d`:

```
xwidth=16.2
set terminal epslatex color size xwidth cm,0.59*xwidth font 9 dashlength 2.0 round standalone
set output "Pernal12.tex"
unset border
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set multiplot

####
set size 0.55,1.166
set origin 0.02,-0.035

set xrange [0:10]
set yrange [-6:6]
set zrange [0:10]

unset tics

set view map
set samples 1000
set isosamples  1000, 1000
set palette defined (0 "white", 10 "black")
set cbrange[0:10]
unset colorbox

t={1,0}
e0={1,0}
eta={0.1,0}
i={0.0,1.0}
c(x)=sqrt(16*t**2+x**2)
a(x)=sqrt(2*((4*t/(c(x)-x))**2+1))
A(x)=(1-4*t/(c(x)-x))**2
B(x)=(1+4*t/(c(x)-x))**2
Gbup(x,y)=1/a(x)**2*(A(x)/(y-(e0+t+(c(x)+x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta)+B(x)/(y-(e0+t-(c(x)-x)/2)+x /2+1+i*eta))
Gaup(x,y)=1/a(x)**2*(B(x)/(y-(e0-t+(c(x)+x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta)+A(x)/(y-(e0-t-(c(x)-x)/2)+x/2+1+i*eta))
plot '++' using 1:2:(-imag(Gbup($1,$2)+Gaup($1,$2))/1.01) with image notitle
```

The resulting `.ps` file is 938kB big. If you have the change to use the 5.0rc2 version, you can get down to 106kB with the `level3` terminal option.

BTW: It is quite pointless to use `set size` and `set origin` and also set all margins with `set lmargin`, `bmargin`, `tmargin` and `rmargin`. See also [Big data surface plots: Call gnuplot from tikz to generate bitmap and include automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23927580/2604213).