# Epslatex and multiplot gives superposed graph

Tags: bash, latex, gnuplot

I am using the following script in order to

```
ts=10

gnuplot <<EOF
set terminal epslatex color
set output "scaling.tex"
set lmargin at screen 0
set rmargin at screen 1

set multiplot layout 1,2

set key off
set xlabel "$P$"
set ylabel "Speedup"
set xtics (1,4,8,16,32,64)
plot "scaling.dat" u 1:($ts/\$2) w lp

set key off
set xlabel "$P$"
set ylabel "Efficiency"
set xtics (1,4,8,16,32,64)
plot "scaling.dat" u 1:($ts/\$2/\$1) w lp

unset multiplot
unset output
unset terminal

EOF
```

The problem is that the two graphs appear superposed on the eps file (not enough reputation to post the image, sorry). Does anyone see the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is your `lmargin` and `rmargin` settings. I would suggest that you remove these lines and see what the default output looks like. If you want to specify margins manually, you should do so separately for each of the two graphs. For example, you could use `set lmargin at screen 0; set rmargin at screen 0.5` for the first plot, then `set lmargin at screen 0.5; set rmargin at screen 1` for the second.

If you're defining your layout manually, you probably don't need to also be using `layout 1,2` at the same time.

Comment: Yes, this was the problem! Thank you. I added this lines when I pot a single graph to obtain a better result when using LaTeX (in particular classic thesis). Do you know how i reduce spaces between plots in order to give a better outlook at the result?

Comment: No problem. As I suggested, try changing the margin settings for each individual plot to reduce the space between them. Here's a [useful link from Gnuplotting](http://www.gnuplotting.org/multiplot-placing-graphs-next-to-each-other/) that explains a bit more about it.

Comment: @NomeCognome `layout` as a multiplot option does not work well with `set margin`, you should use one *or* the other. Using margins, horizontal spacing between plots is achieved using both `set lmargin` and `set rmargin` before *each* plot in such a way that the first `rmargin` and the second `lmargin` are offset by the distance you want between the right vertical line of your first plot and the left vertical line of the second one (assuming you're plotting from left to right).

Comment: @NomeCognome See my answer to [Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213) for a quite general way of setting _all_ margins in a multiplot layout.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you to everybody!