# Gnuplot Function with Multiple Statements

Tags: gnuplot

## Question

Is it possible to define functions which have multiple statements defined within?

## Context

I want to automate some of the calculations involved in creating stacked plots by defining functions.  In particular, I was hoping to have something like

```
mp_setup(bottom_margin, top_margin) = \
    set tmargin 0; \
    set bmargin 0; \
    mp_available_height = 1.0 - top_margin - bottom_margin; \
    mp_current_height = bottom_margin;
mp_plot(plot_height) = \
    mp_plot_size = plot_height * mp_available_height; \
    set origin 0,mp_current_height; \
    set size 1,mp_plot_size; \
    mp_current_height = mp_current_height + mp_plot_size;
```

with the intended usage being:

```
...
set multiplot
mp_setup(0.05, 0.05)

mp_plot(1.0/3.0)
plot ...

mp_plot(2.0/3.0)
plot ...
```

and this should automatically result in the plots being nicely stacked without me having to calculate the origin and size for each graph.

## Problem

The way of defining the functions above doesn't work because it seems like the parsing of the function definition ends at the first occurrence of `;`; but these semicolons are necessary in order to separate each statement (otherwise, we have `set tmargin 0 set bmargin 0...` which is invalid).

It also seems like Gnuplot doesn't support any way of grouping statement (like `{...}` in C/C++); or at least, I have never come across it.

## Possible Solution

The only method I know to store multiple functions and evaluate them is using macros:

```
mp_setup = "<as above>"
mp_plot = "<as above>"
```

But the issue here is that macros do not allow for arguments to be passed in and instead each variable would have to be declared beforehand as follows:

```
...
set multiplot
top_margin = 0.05
bottom_margin = 0.05
@mp_setup

plot_height = 1.0/3.0
@mp_plot
plot ...

 plot_height = 2.0/3.0
@mp_plot
plot ...
```

This solution, although it should work, is not quite as elegant.

Is there no other way of doing this?

Comment: I have proposed two solutions to this in my answer to [Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213). One using an approach similar to yours, but using `eval`, and one using the syntax `set multiplot layout ... margins ... spacing ...`, which is new in version 5.0 (released on New Year).

Comment: @Christoph Thanks, I'll have a look at that in the case of this multiplot; however, I'm still wondering whether there's a nice way of having functions with multiple statements in Gnuplot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it isn't possible to define such functions. In gnuplot user-defined functions cannot contain `set`, `unset` or other commands. Only those kind of expressions are allowed, which return numerical or string variables. Here, you can have several expressions, separated by comma:

```
a = 0
f(x) = (a = a + 1, a + x)
print f(1)
print f(1)
```

Besides your solution to use macros (`@var`), I prefer constructing strings inside the function and calling `eval`:

```
set_margin(s, v) = sprintf('set %smargin at screen %f;', s, v)
set_margins(l, r, b, t) = set_margin('l', l).set_margin('r', r).set_margin('b', b).set_margin('t', t)

eval(set_margins(0.1, 0.95, 0.15, 0.98))
```

For your specific case of a multiplot layout you can also see [Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213).

Answer (score 0):

You can do like that

```
mp_setup(bottom_margin, top_margin)=(tmargin=0,bmargin=0,mp_available_height=1.0 -top_margin-bottom_margin,mp_current_height=bottom_margin)
```

test:
print mp_setup(0.05,0.05)
==> 0.05

As you mentioned, the grouping statement in the function is not supporting yet.