# How do gnuplot margins work in multiplot mode?

Tags: plot, scripting, gnuplot

I am a bit confused about gnuplot margins. First of all I have no idea what units these things are pointing to. Are they pointing to the canvas coordinates OR are they a fraction of the canvas coordinates. Do they behave the same in gnuplot mode and multiplot mode?

My problem arises when plotting some data in multiplot mode. I am plotting to the screen (wtx terminal). Let's just say I am bungling things badly - I get plots off the canvas, or very small unreadable plots.

Without margins the first plot is flush against the top of the canvas, so naturally I want to push it down a bit.

Can someone explain how gnuplot margins work and if they behave the same in multiplot mode.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, the margins behave very similar in "normal" plotting mode and in multiplot mode. Basically, the margins can have three different "modes":

1. Automatic, which is the default.
2. Setting each margin to a specific size, like `set lmargin 2`. The unit is character widths (or character heights for `tmargin` and `bmargin`).
3. Setting a specific *position* of a border relative to the whole canvas, like `set lmargin at screen 0.1`, which sets the left plot border at 10% of the total canvas width.

The only difference of the `multiplot` mode is, that the reference for the margins in 1. and 2. is given by the sites determined by the `layout` option:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
```

This subdivides the whole canvas in four rectangles of equal size. Now, using

```
set lmargin 1
set rmargin 1
set tmargin 1
set bmargin 1
```

leaves a margin of one character width or height on each side of each subplot with respect to the smaller rectangles:

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
set lmargin 0
set rmargin 0
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set format ''
plot x
plot x**2
plot x**3
plot x**4
unset multiplot
```

[image]

```
set multiplot layout 2,2
set lmargin 1
set rmargin 1
set tmargin 1
set bmargin 1
set format ''
plot x
plot x**2
plot x**3
plot x**4
unset multiplot
```

[image]

If you want to set absolute positions of each border, this becomes more cumbersome, because you have to set four margins for each plot (the `layout` options doesn't have any effect in this case):

```
set multiplot
set lmargin at screen 0.1
set rmargin at screen 0.47
set tmargin at screen 0.97
set bmargin at screen 0.6
plot x
...
```

Gnuplot version 5 offers a quite flexible way to produce equal rectangles, see my answer to [Removing blank gap in gnuplot multiplot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213)

Comment: This is a very comprehensive answer and I am very appreciative. The units do differ whether you use set lmargin or set lmargin  at screen, and this was a source of confusion, which has now been clarified