# How to make sure my plots share same axis while using multiplot in gnuplot?

Tags: plot, gnuplot, axis

I use the following script to plot a matrix file `file.dat` and two points on the same plot.

The problem is that my x and y axis do not overlap for the two different plots.

```
set multiplot
set pm3d map
splot 'file.dat' matrix
unset pm3d
plot '-' w p
> 20, 10
> 30, 40
> e
unset multiplot
```

Comment: Are you sure about `using matrix`? Not just `matrix`?

Comment: type `help margin`  and have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376374/how-do-gnuplot-margins-work-in-multiplot-mode

Comment: @TomSolid  You are right. My apologies. I will make the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try `nonuniform matrix` instead of `splot` and `pm3d map`:

```
set multiplot
set size 1,1
unset colorbox
plot[0:3][0:2] '-' nonuniform matrix with image
12 0 1 2 3
0 5 4 8 9
1 6 4 7 8
2 5 6 2 4
e
e
set size 1,1
plot[0:3][0:2] '-' w p ps 5 lw 4 notitle
2 1.2
2.5 1.2
2.5 1.5
e
unset multiplot
```

[image]

Comment: I am unable to proceed after the following command. It displays:

    `plot[0:3][0:2] '-' nonuniform matrix with image
                              ^
           ';' expected`

Comment: Interesting... can you copy the whole text, begining from (and with) the last `gnuplot> ` ?

Comment: It's working now. I got exact same plot as yours. Yesterday I tried it on another machine. I am not sure if it's because of the different version of gnuplot or something else. Anyway, it's working now. Thank you!
But now I tried with my data file by replacing '-' in `plot[0:3][0:2] '-' nonuniform matrix with image` with my file name. It displays:
warning: Image grid must be at least 2 x 2.

Comment: What is the dimensions of your 'file.dat'? Note, that `nonuniform` needs an extra row and an extra column to specify the x/y coordinates:
>>  <N+1>  <y0>   <y1>   <y2>  ...  <yN>
>>  <x0> <z0,0> <z0,1> <z0,2> ... <z0,N>
>>  <x1> <z1,0> <z1,1> <z1,2> ... <z1,N>
(If I remember well, the value of <N+1> only used in case of binary files. In other cases it is just a padding (arbitrary) item.)