# Gnuplot: Big output file issue using a non-uniform grid (mollweide projection)

Tags: plot, output, gnuplot

I'm using the cairolatex terminal in gnuplot to make a figure using the [Mollweide projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mollweide_projection). I could find the code in [AstroJCT](http://astrojct.blogspot.com.es/2012/01/plotting-2d-map-with-colors-for-3rd.html) and the result looks pretty:

[image]

However, the eps file weighs 17 MB and the pdf file of the image 2 MB. This is pretty big if I want to include several plots in my work. The problem is (I guess) that the data file has ~ 90000 points and every point is being plotted.

Some time ago I had a similar problem and using `plot with image` made the file look the same and be much smaller but this is not the case since I don't have an uniform grid. The datafile has in each row the longitude and latitude and the code I found transforms it into x and y coordinates.

I've tried using `set table` and then using `splot with pm3d` but the result doesn't look as good as it did before (the pdf version looks worse and it weighs almost 2 MB, thus solving nothing):

[image]

How can I get a plot like the first one but being lighter? Drawing a much lower amount of points is not an option since there are blank spots inside the plot then. 
Many thanks.

Gnuplot code example of my program for the first plot:

```
set term cairolatex
set output "depth_ecuatorial.tex"

set border 0
unset xtics
unset ytics
set nokey

mwhigh(x) = 1.0 + -0.919061*(abs(1.0-x))**0.674635
mwmed(x) = mwhigh(x) -0.0807765 + 0.161136*x -0.0796311*x**2
mwlow(x) = mwmed(x) -3.53551e-05 + 0.000645749*x
mwst(x) = x < 0.2 ? mwlow(x) : (x < 0.9 ? mwmed(x) : mwhigh(x) )
mwt(b) = b>0 ? asin(mwst(sin(abs(b)))) : -asin(mwst(sin(abs(b))))
mwx(b,l) = 2.0*sqrt(2.0) * l * cos(mwt(b))
mwy(b,l) = sqrt(2.0) * sin(mwt(b))
lconv(l) = l < pi ? l : l - 2*pi

plot "depth_ecuatorial.txt" using (mwx($2,lconv($1))):(mwy($2,lconv($1))):($3) palette pt 9
```

Some lines from the datafile:

```
0.0 -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.0210139976829 -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.0420279953657 -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.0630419930486 -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.0840559907315 -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.105069988414  -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.126083986097  -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.14709798378   -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.168111981463  -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
0.189125979146  -1.57079632679  0.004206772736096981
```

Comment: Try to save into jpeg!

Comment: But then I can't have all the text created by Latex is it done when I use the cairolatex terminal. It is true that the plot file is much smaller though.

Comment: You have written that some time ago `image` had helped you. If you have a non uniform grid, use `nonuniform matrix` (as there http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36865462/how-to-make-sure-my-plots-share-same-axis-while-using-multiplot-in-gnuplot/36886057#36886057)

Comment: I don't think that works since I don't really have a grid and you're required to provide one (even if it's non uniform) when using `matrix`. Anyways, I've answered with something that works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some digging I could find the script from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/131106/107530 that does exactly what I needed. Using that, the size of the pdf plot version went down from several MBs to 100 KB.

That script can be used for ANY plot that has a big output file.