# Multiplot stacked over each other vertically, with same x axis in gnuplot

Tags: plot, graph, gnuplot

Following is the code I use and below that is my output. I want to remove all the spaces in between my subplots and the x labels. A sample of what I need is provided in the link at the end the only difference being I need all the boxes to be of same size.

```
set terminal jpeg

set output "mul.jpeg"

set multiplot

set xr[0:10]
set ylabel "y"
set format y ""
set key off

set size 1,0.25

set origin 0.0,0.0;
set xlabel "x"
plot sin(x)
replot sin(2*x)

set origin 0.0,0.25;
set format x ""
plot cos(x)
replot cos(2*x)

set origin 0.0,0.50;
set format x ""
plot sin(x)

set origin 0.0,0.75;
set format x ""
plot cos(x)

unset multiplot
```

[image: multiplot_example]

What I actually need is something like this:

https://inspirehep.net/record/1345236/files/hada_fig2.png

Thank you for any help!

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19133002/2604213

Comment: Thank you @Christoph . I was missing to make use of margins.

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to produce a vertically stacked chart like the one in your original picture, so +1 for a solution hidden as a question ;)

Answer (score 6):

From gnuplot 5.0, you can use the solution offered by @Raphael_Roth of setting `margins` to zero, but should also use the `margins` option of `multiplot`, to allow space for the tic labels and xlabel at the bottom.

E.g,

```
set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set lmargin 1
set rmargin 1

set multiplot layout 4,1 margins 0.05,0.95,.1,.99 spacing 0,0

set xrange [0:10]
unset xtics
plot sin(x), sin(2*x)
plot cos(x), cos(2*x)
plot sin(x)

set xtics
plot cos(x)

unset multiplot
```

Comment: It points at `margins` in `set multiplot layout 4,1 margins 0.05,0.95,.1,.99 spacing 0,0` saying "invalid or duplicate option"

Comment: Which version of gnuplot do you have? This works from 5.0, I'll add that to answer.

Comment: Oh okay. I have 4.6. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: You may find it easier to upgrade than to tweak your gnuplot script, then!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `multiplot layout`, but it's a hassle to get it nice with the labels and tics (as they overlapp or don't fit into the canvas)

```
set terminal jpeg

set output "mul.jpeg"

set tmargin 0
set bmargin 0
set lmargin 1
set rmargin 1

unset xtics
unset ytics
set multiplot layout 4,1

set xr[0:10]
plot sin(x), sin(2*x)
plot cos(x), cos(2*x)
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)

unset multiplot
```

The other possibility is to set the margins and/or origin of each plot separately as explained in these SO answers: [multiplot - stacking 3 graphs on a larger canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19131509/multiplot-stacking-3-graphs-on-a-larger-canvas/19133002#19133002) and [How do gnuplot margins work in multiplot mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29376374/how-do-gnuplot-margins-work-in-multiplot-mode)