# Gnuplot - Multiplot - Configuration per graph

Tags: plot, gnuplot

is it possible to have a configuration per graph in multiplot ?

```
set yrange [0:100]; set key;
plot "comparison.txt" using 1:3 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "red" with boxes; unset y2label; unset key; unset ytics
plot "" using 1:17 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "orange" with boxes; 
plot "" using 1:31 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "green" with boxes; set y2label "Process CPU time, %";
```

I want only one first graph in my row to have key, and only last key in my row to have y2label. Is there a way to set this things only per-single plot in multiplot ?

Upd: here is monster script that i finished up with:

```
clear
reset

cd "C:/tests"

ymultiplier=250
countMetrics=9

set grid
unset xtics
#----------STYLES
set tmargin 6
set rmargin 3
set style fill solid
set style data lines
set style fill  transparent solid 0.50 noborder
do for [i=1:10] {
    set style line i linewidth 5
}
set datafile separator comma
#---------------

set output './foursome.png'
set terminal png truecolor nocrop enhanced font arial 12 size 1600,ymultiplier*countMetrics

set multiplot layout countMetrics,4 rowsfirst

set yrange [0:100]; unset key; set lmargin 6;  set tmargin 2.5;
plot "normal.txt" using 1:3 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "red" with boxes; unset y2label; unset key; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:17 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "orange" with boxes; 
plot "" using 1:31 title "Process: CPU time" lt rgb "dark-green" with boxes; set y2label "Process CPU time, %";  
plot "" using 1:3 lt rgb "red" with boxes, "" using 1:17 lt rgb "orange" with boxes, "" using 1:31 lt rgb "dark-green" with boxes

set yrange [200:600]; unset y2label; set ytics; set lmargin 6; set format y;  set tmargin; unset title; 
plot "" using 1:($4/1e6) title "Process: Private Bytes" lt rgb "red"; unset key; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:($18/1e6) title "Process: Private Bytes" lt rgb "orange"; 
plot "" using 1:($32/1e6) title "Process: Private Bytes" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Process: Private Bytes, MB";
plot "" using 1:($4/1e6) lt rgb "red", "" using 1:($18/1e6) lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:($32/1e6) lt rgb "dark-green"; 

set yrange [200:600]; unset y2label; set ytics; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:($8/1e6) title "Process: Working Set" lt rgb "red";  unset key; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:($22/1e6) title "Process: Working Set" lt rgb "orange"; 
plot "" using 1:($36/1e6) title "Process: Working Set" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Process: Memory usage, MB";
plot "" using 1:($8/1e6) lt rgb "red", "" using 1:($22/1e6) lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:($36/1e6) lt rgb "dark-green"; 

set yrange [-50:1100]; set ytics; unset y2label; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:9 title "Java heap Usage" with boxes lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:23 title "Java heap Usage" with boxes lt rgb "orange"
plot "" using 1:37 title "Java heap Usage" with boxes lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Java heap Usage"; 
plot "" using 1:9 with boxes lt rgb "red", "" using 1:23 with boxes lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:37 with boxes lt rgb "dark-green";

unset y2label; set ytics; set yrange [0:150]; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:($10/1e6) title "Java heap Max" lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:($24/1e6) title "Java heap Max" lt rgb "orange";
plot "" using 1:($38/1e6) title "Java heap Max" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Java heap Max, MB";
plot "" using 1:($10/1e6) lt rgb "red", "" using 1:($24/1e6) lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:($38/1e6) lt rgb "dark-green"

set yrange [0:300];  unset y2label; set ytics; unset key; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:12 title "Garbage Collection Time" lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:26 title "Garbage Collection Time" lt rgb "orange"
plot "" using 1:40 title "Garbage Collection Time" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Collection Time, S";
plot "" using 1:12 lt rgb "red" , "" using 1:26 lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:40 lt rgb "dark-green"


set yrange [0:3000];  unset key; set ytics; unset y2label; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:13 title "MarkSweepCompact CollectionCount" lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:27 title "MarkSweepCompact CollectionCount" lt rgb "orange"
plot "" using 1:41 title "MarkSweepCompact CollectionCount" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Mark Sweep Compact Collection Count";
plot "" using 1:13 lt rgb "red", "" using 1:27 lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:41 lt rgb "dark-green"

set yrange[85:110]
set ytics; unset y2label; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:7 title "Process: Handle count" lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:21 title "Process: Handle count" lt rgb "orange"
plot "" using 1:35 title "Process: Handle count" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Process: Handle count";
plot "" using 1:7 lt rgb "red", "" using 1:21 lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:35  lt rgb "dark-green"

set yrange[200:600]; set ytics; unset y2label; set lmargin 6; set format y; 
plot "" using 1:($8/1e6) title "Process: Thread count" lt rgb "red"; set lmargin 0; set format y ""; 
plot "" using 1:($22/1e6) title "Process: Thread count" lt rgb "orange"
plot "" using 1:($36/1e6) title "Process: Thread count" lt rgb "dark-green"; set y2label "Process: Thread count, 10x6";
plot "" using 1:($8/1e6) lt rgb "red", "" using 1:($22/1e6) lt rgb "orange", "" using 1:($36/1e6) lt rgb "dark-green"

unset multiplot

set output './dummy.dat'
#JMX - start from 10-16
```

Comment: What is your current result, and what exactly do you want? Please be a bit more specific. And please give a full but minimal working example (using e.g. sin(x) and cos(x) instead of data which we don't have). Yes, you must shift around with appropriate `set` and `unset` commands after your first and before your last plot.

Comment: I want to build graph for multiplot 9x4. I need titles only for top plots, xticks only for left plots, xtitle only for right graphs. I didn't find a way to do it withought monstrous graph.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. If you `set` something is enough you `unset` after (or another set of parameters):

```
set multiplot layout 3,1
  # Here the 1st plot
    set yrange [0:100]
    set key
       plot sin(x) t "plot 1"
  # Here the 2st plot
    unset key
    set xlabel "X of the second plot " 
       plot cos(x) t "plot 2"
  # Here the 3rd plot
    # unset key # is not needed 
    set xlabel "X of the last plot " 
    set y2label "Process CPU time, %";  # better before if you want it acts
   plot cos(1.5*x) t "plot 3"

unset multiplot
```

Comment: I found it to expensive - since each row and column graph have different values:
first row should have titles, 
first column - should have xtics
last column - x values.
Also i wanted distance between columns to be narrower, except first most left one

Comment: @saikek Yes, this is indeed quite expensive, especially for a large graph. But that's the way to go. Maybe you'll find my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213 helpful about how to better layout plots on a grid.

Comment: :-) Of course it is _expensive_: you are doing 36 plots and 54 curves. did you expect it was for free?! :-) If the link of @Christoph is not enough you can think a little different: remember that ___gnuplot_ is able to `call` scripts and to pass variables to that script__. So you can define some linestyles,  create your sub script with one block of 4 plots. In the main script between the `set` and `unset multiplot` you can `call` for 9 times the sub script with the variables you need (value for yrange,  margin, strings for curve title and y2range...). BTW that's a totally different question.

Comment: @saikek If you mind try to reduce your _monster script_ in a more [_cultured, sophisticated...man about town_(01:20:31,030)](http://www.opensubtitles.org/en/subtitles/4694176/young-frankenstein-en). ;) and if you stop with some problem post another question and put a comment here.