# gnuplot multiplot - layout and scale

Tags: layout, gnuplot, scale

### Multiplot scale

I don't really understand the idea behind the `scale` option in the multiplot command of gnuplot.

`set multiplot layout 2,2 scale x,y`

There can be only one pair of values for the whole multiplot - what is it possibly used for? Is it really just for scaling *all* the graphs in the multiplot? What for?

It would make sense to me, if you could assign scale factors the the individual layout parts, in that I would say: first column takes 70% of the width, second column takes 30% etc but here?

I'd appreciate any explanation! Plus, is there a built-in function to generate multiplots using the "layout" option in the described manner?

### Multiplot Layout

I want a multiplot layout consisting of a 4rows,2columns grid. Both columns should fill 45% of the space each, leaving a 10% white gap at the right which will be used for a label set right next to the second column via `set label at graph 1,0.5 "text"`. (Actually, this means a 45% / 55% ratio of the two columns.)

This works with this MWE

```
set multiplot

mystring = "This is\na multiline\nlabel"

width = 0.45
height = 0.25


#1 1
set origin 0,1-height
set size width,height   #remains the same
plot sin(x)


#1 2
set origin width,1-height
set label at graph 1,0.5 offset 2,1 mystring
plot cos(x)
unset label


#2 1
set origin 0,1-2*height
plot sin(x*2)


#2 2
set origin width,1-2*height
mystring = "This "This is\na different\nlabel"
set label at graph 1,0.5 offset 2,1 mystring
plot cos(x)
unset label

#etc...

unset multiplot
```

However, I want to put some labels (no title etc) above the first row. If I make space via `set tmargin <val>` for the first row, then the plots get squished, not shifted. Is there a way to somehow "add whitespace" around the plots, the top in particular? Or would I need to make the `height` variable a tad smaller and adjust accordingly?

Plus, I made no `size` settings, as you see, but used proportionals in the range of [0,1]. When using the epslatex terminal, I'll provide overall size information. Can I expect the ratios to preserve?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213

Comment: How did I miss the margins option, thank you........... anyways -  would you or someone still comment on the other issues in my post, please?

Comment: Wait: I already tried the margin option, it does only work in the auto-layout mode. I already found the link during my research, yet I don't think it provides the solution to my problem. Spacing doesn't work outside auto-layout and auto-layout can not provide *different* scaling options for individual rows/columns...

Comment: Yes, that works only for equal plot sizes. But, to be honest, from your question I did not understand which kind of layout you want, because you somehow talk about equal and different column widths.