# Setting the gnuplot key on a multiplot in the margin without shrinking a panel

Tags: gnuplot

Suppose we are working with the following multiplot:

```
set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst

unset key
set size ratio 0.625
plot cos(x)

set size ratio 0.625
set key bmargin center vertical maxrows 1
set xlabel "blah"
plot sin(x)
```

How can I ensure that the last panel has the same dimensions as the top panel? Here is the current result:

[image]

Comment: you can set fixed margins, e.g. `set margins 2,2,2,2`, then at least the sizes of the two plots will be the same, however, I assume you were hoping for some automatic calculation of the necessary margins.

Comment: Use `set multiplot margins ... spacing ...`, see e.g. the first example in https://stackoverflow.com/a/23936306/2604213

Comment: Thanks @Christoph, I've read your other answer and another one of your answers regarding the specifics of <left>, <right>, <bottom>, <top> in the margin setting. When I use `set multiplot margins 0.1,0.98,0.2,0.98 spacing 0.1,0.1` I am seeing this: https://imgur.com/a/mPKp3nE. It looks like it is 'adding' another column to the right of the plot but I might be mistaken. How do I resolve this so that the plots are centered?

Comment: Sorry, it my comment was to highlight the `margins` and `spacing` properties. You must of course also include the `layout` property. The line `set multiplot layout 1,2 margins 0.1,0.98,0.2,0.98 spacing 0.1,0.1; plot sin(x); plot cos(x)` works fine for me.

Comment: I appreciate the response; that didn't work for me when I integrated it into my original code in the OP. I had to use `set multiplot layout 2,1 rowsfirst margins 0.33,0.33,0.1925,0.92 spacing 0.1,0.1` given the 0.625 size ratio for each plot. The margins are off /slightly/ when I compare it to a plot with only one panel. Wish there was a way to automatically center the plot when the plot size ratio is set for a multiplot.